# How do you ignore/persist values in MVC when your view-model doesn't have as many fields as your domain model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, fluent-nhibernate, viewmodel, automapper

I have a site where I'm using fluentNhibernate and Asp.net MVC.  I have an Edit view that allows user to edit 8 of the 10 properties for that record (object).  When you submit the form and the Model binds, the two un-editable fields come back in the view-model as Empty strings or as default DateTime values depending on the type of property.

Because I'm also using AutoMapper to map my view-model to my Domain Entity, I cannot just load a fresh copy of my object from the database and manually set the 2 missing properties.  Whats the best way to persist those fields that I don't want edited?

One way that does work is to persist the values in hidden Input fields on my View.  That works but feels gross.  I appreciate any recommendations.  Is there a way in my AutoMapper to configure this desired functionality?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, So I guess I'm not trying to ignore the fields, I'm trying to make sure that I don't persist null or empty string values.  Ignoring the fields in AutoMapper does just that, they get ignored and are null when I attempt to map them before Saved to my repository.

Comment: Is there a reason why the un-editable fields are even part of the view-model?

Comment: Currently they are not part of the view-model, which appears to be part of the problem.  The fields are 'AddedBy' and 'DateAdded'.  Once this object is created those should never be changed.  I was trying to wire up an Edit view without losing that data.  Using Automapper null's that data out when I map from my view-model to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asp.net mvc DefaultModelBinder is extensible, and you can override it to create your own binding schema. But this will involve more work than two "hidden Input fields", which , in my point of view, is not that gross.

Comment: I think the hidden input fields is gross. Besides the fact that you're sending data to the client just so that it can be sent back, it can also be modified. I use non-editable fields for things like ownership, creation date, etc.

Comment: JW, its not that 2 hidden input fields are gross - but the next view I'll be working with will contain more like 10 hidden input fields.  Thats when I started questioning this method.  This is an internal application but James S has a good point too - these fields can be tampered with.

Comment: While I am hesitant to believe this is the best solution, it is the solution that I will be using.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Automapper to ignore the 2 properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValuefff, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

[Possible related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest).

Comment: I've tried this, I just get null values instead of empty strings and the DateTime properties come back with default values.

Comment: Well, I take that back - your solution does work if I load the object from the repository before mapping.  This way the ignored fields won't overwrite the freshly loaded object - only the fields that I want to be updated will be.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i rejected this answer because as i mention in my first comment, Ignore() causes the property to be 'newed' up.  That is, Ignoring a DateTime property sets it to something like '01/01/0001' and Ignoring a string property sets it to "", not null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the AutoMapper.Map overload that also accepts TEntity?!

```
entity = Mapper.Map(viewmodel, entity);
```

As long as you do not have the properties on your viewmodel, it won't change the values on your entity. It takes the entity being passed in and applies only the properties from the viewmodel back to the entity.