# How get AutoMapper to: ignore non mapped properties, include conventional mapping and work with QueryableExtensions

Tags: c#, automapper, iqueryable

I've found two solution to ignore non mapped properties but [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8071038/1133338) also ignore the conventional mappings, and the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest/6474397#6474397) doesn't work with [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions.cs) to return an IQueryable (don't know why but I get the error *Argument types do not match*).

Does anyone has a solution to ignore non mapped properties that covers both aspects above?

Comment: Just informational comment, does IQueryable work with other AutoMapper maps? Wouldn't you want to "realize" the results of IQueryable and not attempt to copy to a DTO? Mapping something to IQueryable does not seem like what you want to do as your DTO's usually cross a process boundary or are served up as JSON.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using and what type of IQueryable expression are you mapping? LINQ to SQL, LINQ to EF, other?

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing I already updated earlier today to the latest 2.2.1 after reading (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/163) but with no luck (still same error). IQueryable works fine with other maps, including using the "IgnoreAllUnmapped" map. I don't want to "realize" IQueryable otherwise it would bring a bunch of unnecessary data since I'll be calling from GetAll() or Table() in the repository.

Comment: I rolled back my test bed to 2.1.262 to attempt to duplicate your problem and see if I can get the IgnoreAllNonExisting to work.

Comment: This is the only advice I have for you: try making use of the CanResolveValue() inside of the loop over the unmapped property names:

`if (existingMaps.GetPropertyMaps().Any(pm => pm.CanResolveValue() && pm.SourceMember.Name == property))
{
    expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
}`

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing no luck

Comment: At a loss without a simple test case to help you. I've not been able to duplicate what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

When using [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) you have to be explicit with some type conversions, such as `int?` to `int`. This is probably the source of the "Argument types do not match" exception.

If you have many properties that need a type conversion -- like if you had many other properties where you find you are doing `c.MyVariable ?? 0` -- you can instead define a conversion rule and not have to be explicit about every property.

Normally, to do type conversions in Automapper, you would use `ConvertUsing` but when using QueryableExtensions, you need to instead use [`ProjectUsing`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#custom-type-conversion).

You could use the following line and it will take care of all mappings from `int?` to `int` without the need to explicitly specify the mappings for each property:

```
cfg.CreateMap<int?, int>().ProjectUsing(src => src.HasValue ? src.Value : 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Chaining at the end of the mapping with the `.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());` worked for me. This should be the last method in the method chain.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was in this line of code

`.ForMember(p => p.Gender, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.GenderCode))`

where p.Gender was of type int and GenderCode of type int?. so changing to

`.ForMember(p => p.Gender, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.GenderCode ?? 0))`

fixed the problem. What made it hard to troubleshoot is that the mapping code above was working until I try to return IQueryable.