# Flatten nested object

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 6.2.2, I have two source models that share an `Id` property:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using AutoMapper;

public class Outer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public Inner Bar { get; set; }
}
public class Inner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
    public string Qux { get; set; }
    public string Bof { get; set; }
}
public class FlatDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
    public string Qux { get; set; }
    public string Bof { get; set; }
}
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Outer, FlatDto>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Foo))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Baz, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.Baz))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Qux, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.Qux))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Bof, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.Bof));
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Outer model = new Outer
        {
            Id = 1,
            Foo = "FooString",
            Bar = new Inner
            {
                Id = 2,
                Baz = "BazString",
                Qux = "QuxString",
                Bof = "BofString"
            }
        };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(config);

        FlatDto dto = mapper.Map<Outer, FlatDto>(model);
        Trace.Assert(model.Id == dto.Id);
        Trace.Assert(model.Foo == dto.Foo);
        Trace.Assert(model.Bar.Baz == dto.Baz);
        Trace.Assert(model.Bar.Qux == dto.Qux);
        Trace.Assert(model.Bar.Bof == dto.Bof);
    }
}
```

I want `FlatDto.Id` to come from `Outer` and the other parameters all by name. AutoMapper's convention in this case is pretty clear however I cannot modify these properties. It's currently mapped explicitly with `ForMember` for every dest property. The solution for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576237/a-better-way-to-use-automapper-to-flatten-nested-objects) actually is even longer.

Does a more elegant solution exist for this case where both models contain several fields and only one overlaps and requires explicit handling?

Comment: So do you want `Inner` inside of `Outer`? And what do you want to do with `FlatDto`?

Comment: The source models are Outer and Inner, I am flattening them in to an instance of FlatDto.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7). There is also smth similar in the question you linked to.

Comment: The question has been updated to include a working sample.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, that extension throws an ArgumentException exception stating `Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'` in the `mapFrom` assignment.

Comment: You're welcome to fix it then :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution (without changing code even you modified Outer/Inner in the future) is:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<Inner, FlatDto>();
    c.CreateMap<Outer, FlatDto>().BeforeMap((s, t) => Mapper.Map(s.Bar, t));
});
```

Be aware that:

1. You need to change if you are using instance mappers instead of static `.Map` method of "global" mapper.
2. Properties with same name in both `Inner` and `Outer` will be mapped twice, and the `Outer` has a higher priority, be careful with possible side effects.

**EDIT** Since you are using instance mappers and profiles, the instance `IMapper` can't be accessed inside a profile, we need to register the mappings dynamic. The following code, just like the code snippet in the question, essentially uses `.ForMember`, with the arguments built in dynamic expressions.

```
class TestProfile : Profile
{
    public TestProfile()
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        Func<PropertyInfo, bool> filter = p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite;

        var outerProperties = typeof(Outer).GetProperties(flags).Where(filter).ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
        var innerProperties = typeof(Inner).GetProperties(flags).Where(filter);
        var mappingProperties = innerProperties.Where(p => !outerProperties.ContainsKey(p.Name));

        //code above gets the properties of Inner that needs to be mapped

        var outerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Outer));
        var accessBar = Expression.Property(outerParameter, nameof(Outer.Bar));
        var map = CreateMap<Outer, FlatDto>();
        var mapExp = Expression.Constant(map);

        foreach (var property in mappingProperties)
        {
            var accessProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(accessBar, property);
            var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Outer), property.PropertyType);
            var funcExp = Expression.Lambda(funcType, accessProperty, outerParameter);
            //above code builds s => s.Bar.Qux

            var configType = typeof(IMemberConfigurationExpression<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Outer), typeof(FlatDto), typeof(object));
            var configParameter = Expression.Parameter(configType);
            var mapFromMethod = configType
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(m => m.Name == "MapFrom" && m.IsGenericMethod)
                .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
            var invokeMapFrom = Expression.Call(configParameter, mapFromMethod, funcExp);
            var configExp = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(configType), invokeMapFrom, configParameter);
            //above code builds opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.Qux)

            var forMemberMethod = map.GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(m => m.Name == "ForMember" && !m.IsGenericMethod);
            var invokeForMember = Expression.Call(mapExp, forMemberMethod, Expression.Constant(property.Name), configExp);
            //above code builds map.ForMember("Qux", opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.Qux))

            var configAction = Expression.Lambda<Action>(invokeForMember);
            configAction.Compile().Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Looks very huge code but in fact you can(and should) put the get property/method snippet somewhere else, the foreach loop itself uses them to build an expression to invoke. It's quite clean and effective.

Comment: How do perform this within a profile using the instance API?