# More automatic way to use automapper to map to Entity Framework objects

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am mapping quite a few WCF Data Contracts to Entity Framework Classes.

For every class I have to do this kind of thing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyContractClass, MyDalClass>()
    .ForMember(x => x.EntityKey, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.SomeAssociation, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.SomeAssociationReference, opt=> opt.Ignore())
    // Repeat 
    // the 
    // last 
    // /two 
    // lines 
    // for 
    // every 
    // single 
    // association
    // (Some classes have a lot of associations)
    ;
```

Is there an easier way?  Some way to rule out all the extra stuff put in by EntityFramework?

Or does this just have to be done by hand?

NOTE: I have extensively evaluated the POCO template and it does not work for my scenario.  Please do not just recommend that instead of Automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your contract class doesn't have the association properties, you could use [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest/6474397#6474397) to ignore them all in one statement:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyContractClass, MyDalClass>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using T4 templates to generate the mappings from the EDMX model. This works very well and has saved me a lot of time so far. The idea is from [this guy](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/06/entity-framework-v4-end-to-end-application-strategy-part-2-data-layer/). You can download his templates and customize them to work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EntitiesToDTOs](http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com) which is simpler than AutoMapper. You don't have to write the map, neither configurate it. It is all automatically generated by the tool.