# How to use Ignore globally in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

Here is how it looks like right now. DestinationA and DestinationB are derived from some DestinationBase class. And I need to ignore some common properties for all these derived class. Is there anyway to apply these ignore options **globally** without having to repeat for all derived destination classes?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceA, DestinationA>()
      .ForMember(d => d.PropA, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropB, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropC, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceB, DestinationB>()
      .ForMember(d => d.PropA, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropB, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropC, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DestinationBase>().ForAllSource()
      .ForMember(d => d.PropA, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropB, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(d => d.PropC, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore all unmapped properties globally.
Although this contradict the main benefit of automapper, allows to make explicit mapping only:
This is for Automapper 6:

```
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MyProfile());
        // ignore all unmapped properties globally
        cfg.ForAllMaps((map, exp) => exp.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore()));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There's now a method FindTypeMapFor which makes this extension method even smaller (and more efficient?):

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonMapped<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        foreach (var property in Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>().GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
        return expression;
    }
```

Comment: Automapper 8 dosn't contain FindTypeMapFor seems like AM is evolving so fast all answers are useless. I'm getting a feeling AutoMapper is becoming useless

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came across this old question while searching for help.  I ended up coming up with the following solution.  Maybe it's helpful to someone else...

I have several classes derived from a base class.  I want to exclude a property of that base class from all mappings of any class that derives from the base.  After creating my mappings (and without specifying any ignore options), I do this:

```
foreach(var map in Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps())
{
    if (typeof(MyBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(map.DestinationType))
    {
        var propInfo = map.DestinationType.GetProperty("PropertyToIgnore");
        if (propInfo != null) {
            map.FindOrCreatePropertyMapFor(new AutoMapper.Impl.PropertyAccessor(propInfo)).Ignore();
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little brute force because I have to loop through all the type maps, but it gets the job done.

edit: Added a missing { to the if statement

Comment: Thnks a lot...after hours of searching your solution saved me

Comment: Nice solution. This certainly beats having to manually ignore the property for each mapping you might have defined. I would like to know if AutoMapper has any official solutions planned though.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper. I'm getting errors, `GetAllTypeMaps` and `Impl` don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

See the IgnoreAllNonExisting() extension by schdr here:
[AutoMapper: "Ignore the rest"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest)

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> 
    IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var sourceType = typeof (TSource);
    var destinationType = typeof (TDestination);
    var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType.Equals(sourceType) && x.DestinationType.Equals(destinationType));
    foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
    return expression;
}
```

Usage:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

Comment: Thanks, Rami. That helps. But i would still consider it dangerous as It ignores not only the properties you define but everything not mapped. Maybe i will have to tweak this a little bit. Thanks

Comment: @Nay yeah I did a similar thing, where we logged silently any values in product, we let it break on our local build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version added attributes, but these days you can do this. [Docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html#ignoring-members).

```cs
[Ignore]
public string Property { get; set; }
```

Problem with that approach is you leak AutoMapper implementation across domain entities, which isn't great.

A better approach seems to be to setup filtering on the `MapperConfiguration` globally, by defining your own `ShouldMapProperty` delegate, or tacking on a condition to the default implementation. [Docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#global-property-field-filtering).

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ShouldMapField = ...;

    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = ...;
});
```

The default implementations at time of writing are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/51d6c29dc4fbd690529ae83c70799178893e64e5/src/AutoMapper/ProfileMap.cs#L36). Notably, `ShouldMapProperty` falls back if not specified to `p => p.IsPublic()`. So you could do `p => p.IsPublic() && p.DeclaringType != typeof(SomeBaseType) && p.Name == nameof(SomeBaseType.SomePropertyToIgnore)`.