# AutoMapper and EF entities - ignoring all relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map DTOs to entities.

When creating the maps, I always end up ignoring the relationships of the entities, and that usually result in a long, long list. That is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CUSTOMER_DTO, CUSTOMER_ENTITY>()
.ForMember(m => m.ORDERS, o => o.Ignore())
.ForMember(m => m.PAYMENT_METHODS, o => o.Ignore());
// And on and on!
```

Is there a way I can just indicate AutoMapper to ignore every relationship in my entities? Many thanks.

Comment: In a project I'm currently on, we're using an extension method similar to what is described in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming here that your DTOs are simply missing the relationships and you have to ignore them all by hand. If it's the case, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474397/1180426) will be helpful. You could just do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, CustomerEntity>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

And it would ignore every property in `CustomerEntity` that's not present in `CustomerDto`.

As a side note: you should probably change the all-caps names for classes and properties to pascal cased, to follow the general C# coding conventions.