# Automapper maps source to destination but dest values are always null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I'm new to automapper and I'm having a problem with it. In this case the automapper is used to map models(EntityFramework generated) to my own viewmodels. This is what happens, the sourcemodel with it's values is mapped to a destinationmodel but the dest values are always null. What's going on with the values?

Now what did I do:
I referenced the automapper to my project and bootstrapped the mappings.

```
public static void RegisterAutoMapperMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                // Add the mappingprofiles you configured below
                x.AddProfile(new RegistrationViewModelProfile());
            });
        }

    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> IgnoreAllUnmapped<TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
    {
        expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        return expression;
    }

    public class RegistrationViewModelProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, contact>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();
            CreateMap<contact, RegistrationViewModel>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();

            CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, emailaddress>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();
            CreateMap<emailaddress, RegistrationViewModel>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();

            CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, password>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();
            CreateMap<password, RegistrationViewModel>().IgnoreAllUnmapped();

            //Always check if mapping is valid
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
        public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public string contact_givenname { get; set; }
        public string contact_surname_prefix { get; set; }
        public string contact_surname { get; set; }
        public string contact_gender { get; set; }
        public string contact_country { get; set; }
        public string contact_residence { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> contact_birth_date{ get; set; }
        public DateTime create_date { get; set; }
        public ICollection<int> Contact_roles { get; set; }
        public string Emailaddress_verificationkey { get; set; }
    }
```

My model:

```
public partial class contact
    {
        public contact()
        {
            this.contact_connection_rel = new HashSet<contact_connection_rel>();
            this.contact_emailaddress_password_rel = new HashSet<contact_emailaddress_password_rel>();
            this.contact_emailaddress_rel = new HashSet<contact_emailaddress_rel>();
            this.contact_service_role_rel = new HashSet<contact_service_role_rel>();
            this.given_answer = new HashSet<given_answer>();
            this.given_answer1 = new HashSet<given_answer>();
        }

        public int contact_id { get; set; }
        public string contact_initials { get; set; }
        public string contact_givenname { get; set; }
        public string contact_surname_prefix { get; set; }
        public string contact_surname { get; set; }
        public string contact_nickname { get; set; }
        public string contact_gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> contact_birth_date { get; set; }
        public string contact_country { get; set; }
        public string contact_residence { get; set; }
        public string contact_ssn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> create_date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> modify_date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> delete_date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<contact_connection_rel> contact_connection_rel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<contact_emailaddress_password_rel> contact_emailaddress_password_rel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<contact_emailaddress_rel> contact_emailaddress_rel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<contact_service_role_rel> contact_service_role_rel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<given_answer> given_answer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<given_answer> given_answer1 { get; set; }
    }
```

And to test the configuration the following lines are used. The vars contain the destination objects but are always null:

```
contact c = new contact();
contact testC = unitOfWork.ContactRepository.Find(82);

var x = Mapper.Map<contact, RegistrationViewModel>(testC);
var y = Mapper.Map(regModel, c, typeof(RegistrationViewModel), typeof(contact));
var b = Mapper.DynamicMap<RegistrationViewModel, contact>(regModel);
var z = Mapper.Map<RegistrationViewModel, contact>(regModel, c);
var w = Mapper.Map<RegistrationViewModel, contact>(regModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

You're telling AutoMapper to ignore all properties, so nothing gets mapped.

If you just want to ignore non-matching properties, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474397/43846) for one way, otherwise you're going to have to explicitly map each property between the objects.

Comment: OMG, wasted too much time on something stupid! The link in your answer worked for me. Thank you :)