# How to flatten a conditional object in a list in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I have an `Item` that contains a list of `Product`'s which are mapped to their respective `ViewModel` objects using **AutoMapper**.

In my MVC project I have an Action method that displays an `Item` with a selected `Product`. For this i have a `ViewModel` called `ItemDetailsViewModel` that contains the flattened `Item` object, a list of `ProductViewModel`'s and a flattened selected `Product`.

The difficulty I am having is best showing this flattened selected `Product`.

Think of it like eBay where you have an `Item` and you can choose multiple variations e.g. by colour. For me, the multiple variations are the `Products`. When the user selects the `Product` I want to return the `ItemDetails` i.e. the `Item`, the list of `Products` and the selected `Product`.

I was wondering the best way of doing this? At the moment my method is mapping an `Item` to an `ItemDetailsViewModel`, selecting the desired `ProductViewModel` and then specifically mapping each property of the `ProductViewModel` back onto the `ItemDetailsViewModel`. Also, due to the `Item` and `Product` having the same named properties, the last line mapping the product back overwrites the `Item`s id and code.

Any suggestions on how best to configure the mapping?

I've left out the mapping I have in place as it is mostly a direct one-to-one mapping apart from mapping the selected `ProductViewModel` back to the `ItemDetailsViewModel`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>()
    .ReverseMap();

Mapper.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, ItemDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ProductId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.ProductCode, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Code));
```

**Classes**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public IList<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetailsViewModel : ItemViewModel
{
    public int ProductId;
    public string ProductCode;
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult ItemDetails()
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        Id = 1,
        Code = "Item1",
        Products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Code = "Product1" },
            new Product { Id = 2, Code = "Product2" },
            new Product { Id = 3, Code = "Product3" },
        }
    };

    var productCode = "Product2";
    var itemDetailsViewModel = Mapper.Map<ItemDetailsViewModel>(item);

    if (itemDetailsViewModel.Products != null && itemDetailsViewModel.Products.Count > 0)
    {
        ProductViewModel productViewModel = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(productCode))
            productViewModel = itemViewModel.Products.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code.Equals(productCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (productViewModel == null)
            productViewModel = itemViewModel.Products[0];

        Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, ItemDetailsViewModel>(productViewModel, itemDetailsViewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to ignore the properties in `ItemDetailsViewModel` in your mapping from `ProductViewModel` to `ItemDetailsViewModel`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, ItemDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Code, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.ProductId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.ProductCode, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Code));
```

Comment: You can see this answer for an extension method that ignore non existing property in targeted type : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6280647/2310419

Comment: @Marshall777: Not sure that applies here-- in this case the properties *do* exist on the target type, and that's the problem.

Comment: Will give this a go. Any suggestions on how this could be improved? It seems I'm writing/maintaining a lot of "this-to-that" kind of code. Maybe that's the way it has to be due to my implementation.

Comment: To a degree that's part of using viewmodels, at least in my experience. I'll keep thinking of alternative solutions though.