# Automapper flattening multiple complex objects using custom mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, emitmapper

So I have something besides the usual DTO to business mapper and I'm trying to map them with minimal amount of mapping code.

**Setup**

```
public class Target {

    public string propA { get; set; }
    public string propB { get; set; }
    public string propC { get; set; }
    public string propD { get; set; }
    public string propE { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair> Tokens { get; set; }
}

public class Source {
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
    public AnotherClass AnotherClass { get; set; }

}

public class SomeClass {
    public string propA { get; set; }
    public string propB { get; set; }
    public string propDifferent { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair> Tokens { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public string propC { get; set; }
    public string propD { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapper Config**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeClass, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.propE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.propDifferent));


Mapper.CreateMap<AnotherClass, Target>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeClass))
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherClass));
```

Doing this throws

> Error: AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom
>   configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual
>   members on a type.

And I also need to take `AnotherClass.Tokens`, `SomeClass.Tokens` and add it to `Target.Tokens`.

I know I can use `.ConvertUsing` but then I have to define mapping for every property and I lose the advantage of convention based mapping for matching properties.

Is there any other way of achieving this (other than `.ConvertUsing` or mapping every property by hand)?

If not via **Automapper**, is it doable via **EmitMapper**? I guess adding to Tokens list is probably doable via EmitMapper's `PostProcessing`.

**Update**

After a bit of hacking, I found a way:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> FlattenNested<TSource, TNestedSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(TNestedSource);
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
    var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name.ToLowerInvariant());
    var childPropName = typeof (TSource).GetProperties().First(x => x.PropertyType == sourceType).Name;
    var mappableProperties = destinationType.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => sourceProperties.ContainsKey(p.Name.ToLowerInvariant()) &&
                    sourceProperties[p.Name.ToLowerInvariant()].PropertyType ==
                    p.PropertyType)
        .Select(p => new {DestProperty = p.Name, SrcProperty = sourceProperties[p.Name.ToLowerInvariant()].Name});


    foreach (var property in mappableProperties)
    {
        expression.ForMember(property.DestProperty,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetPropertyValue(childPropName).GetPropertyValue(property.SrcProperty)));
    }

    return expression;
}
```

**Note:** I do the `Name.ToLowerInvariant()` to be able to match `AccountID` -> `AccountId` and similar.

**Usage**

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .FlattenNested<Source, SomeClass, Target>()
    .FlattenNested<Source, AnotherClass, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.propE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.propDifferent));
```

I spotted some other properties in `IMappingExpression` that I maybe able to use and cleanup a lot of this. Will update as I find them.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved similar problem:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> FlattenNested<TSource, TNestedSource, TDestination>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TNestedSource>> nestedSelector,
    IMappingExpression<TNestedSource, TDestination> nestedMappingExpression)
{
    var dstProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);

    var flattenedMappings = nestedMappingExpression.TypeMap.GetPropertyMaps()
                                                    .Where(pm => pm.IsMapped() && !pm.IsIgnored())
                                                    .ToDictionary(pm => pm.DestinationProperty.Name,
                                                                    pm => Expression.Lambda(
                                                                        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(nestedSelector.Body, pm.SourceMember),
                                                                        nestedSelector.Parameters[0]));

    foreach (var property in dstProperties)
    {
        if (!flattenedMappings.ContainsKey(property))
            continue;

        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.MapFrom((dynamic)flattenedMappings[property]));
    }

    return expression;
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var nestedMap = CreateMap<Address, CustomerDto>()
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting();

        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .FlattenNested(s => s.Address, nestedMap);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CustomerProfileTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<CustomerProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

`IgnoreAllNonExisting()` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest).

Though it's not universal solution it should be enough for simple cases.

Advantages are:

1. You use AutoMapper to create nested map so you rely on trusted code and also you can use stuff like `RecognizePrefixes` and so on.
2. As you need to specify nested property selector you avoid possible ambiguity when you have multiple nested properties of same type.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm now trying to move away from AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use BeforeMap to instantiate the object:

UPDATE:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
.BeforeMap(( Source, Target) => {
     Source.SomeClass = new SomeClass();
     Source.AnotherClass = new AnotherClass();
 })  
 .AfterMap(( Source, Target) => {
     Target.SomeClass = Mapper.Map<AnotherClass, Target>(Target);
     Target.AnotherClass = Mapper.Map<SomeClass, Target>(Target);
 })
```

That would allow you to map the parent before mapping the individual objects properties.

I think I am getting lost in your base class names but you can call the mapper.Map properties to map the objects.

UPDATE 2:

Based on this code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
.ForMember(dest => **dest**, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeClass))
.ForMember(dest => **dest**, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherClass));
```

Dest there is trying to resolve an object. If you want to resolve only properties on those objects then I would suggest that you specify them.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.propA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeClass.propA
 .ForMember(dest => dest.propB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeClass.propB
 .ForMember(dest => dest.propC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherClass.propC
 .ForMember(dest => dest.propD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherClass.propD
```

Comment: You sure? I get the same exact error with `BeforeMap`.

Comment: `Target` doesn't have `SomeClass` or `AnotherClass`, just the flat properties. And from the error, it seems that only non-flat top level properties can be mapped as such.

Comment: Thanks but that is precisely what I want to avoid. I have hardwired individual properties manually right now but I would like to take advantage of "Auto-Mapping"! :)