# Flattening without prefixed names in child object in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Consider these classes as source:

```
public class SourceParent
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public SourceChild1 Child1 { get; set; }
    public SourceChild2 Child2 { get; set; }
}

public class SourceChild1
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
}

public class SourceChild2
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int J { get; set; }
    public int K { get; set; }
    public int L { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map the source to a destination similar to this:

```
public class Destination
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }

    public int I { get; set; }
    public int J { get; set; }
    public int K { get; set; }
    public int L { get; set; }
}
```

Well, using this configuration, it is possible to do the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceParent, Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child1.A))
    .ForMember(d => d.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child1.B))
    .ForMember(d => d.C, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child1.C))
    .ForMember(d => d.D, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child1.D))
    .ForMember(d => d.I, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child2.I))
    .ForMember(d => d.J, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child2.J))
    .ForMember(d => d.K, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child2.K))
    .ForMember(d => d.L, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Child2.L));
```

Except that, when the child class has *many* properties, all of which having the same name with the parent, this is not a clean way.

Ideally, I'd like to tell AutoMapper to take Source.Child1 and Source.Child2 as a source too, and map every matching property names to the target (instead of specifying every single property); something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceParent, Destination>()
    .AlsoUseSource(s => s.Child1)
    .AlsoUseSource(s => s.Child2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.ConstructUsing` to accomplish this. It's not the cleanest looking thing in the world, but it'll work:

```
/* Map each child to the destination */
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceChild1, Destination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceChild2, Destination>();

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceParent, Destination>()
    .ConstructUsing(src =>
    {
        /* Map A-D from Child1 */
        var dest = Mapper.Map<Destination>(src.Child1);

        /* Map I-L from Child2 */
        Mapper.Map(src.Child2, dest);

        return dest;
    });
/* X will be mapped automatically. */
```

This should successfully map all of the properties.

Unfortunately, a call to `.AssertConfigurationIsValid` will fail, since properties `I` - `L` will not be mapped on the destination type for the mapping from `SourceParent` → `Destination`.

You could, of course, write a call to `.Ignore` for each one, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of getting rid of the nested mapping calls.

Your other option would be to leverage [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26760463/497356) to ignore unmapped properties on each of the mappings.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Actually I ended up doing something similar (doing the same thing using `AfterMap`). But I'll leave the question unanswered for another day or two, to see if anyone else comes with a "cleaner" answer.