# Automapper unmapped members were found - even after I have mapped these members

Tags: c#, automapper

I have scoured the web and I can't figure out why in Automapper 6.2.1 I am having these issues. I [have](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1395) looked [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359999/auto-mapper-unmapped-members-were-found) many [tutorials](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper), [guides](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192900/application-development/how-to-work-with-automapper-in-c.html) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241708/automapper-mapper-already-initialized-error) and come up with nothing.

I am getting this error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Unmapped properties:
>   Title
>   Subtitle
>   ProductType
>   Language
>   Description

However I have created mappings for these properties. I'm not sure why I am having this issue.

I have created an `AutoMapperConfig` class that is setup like this:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Shop, SearchViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Title, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.TITLE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Subtitle, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.SUB_TITLE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.ProductType, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.PRODUCT_TYPE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Language, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.PRODUCT_LANGUAGE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Description, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.BRIEF_DESC));  
            });
        }
```

Then in my `Global.asax` in the `Application_Start()` method I have this line:

```
AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
```

I am trying to use this in my controller like this:

```
var searchResults = Mapper.Map<List<Shop>, SearchViewModel>(shopList);
```

After I hit that line it throws that exception. I'm not sure *why* since I have created maps for all of those properties.

Comment: Try creating a static class `public static class AutoMapperConfig` and static method `public static EntityMap` instead of `Initialize` and call it like `EntityMap.EntityMapper.Map....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  datatype of `searchResults` is wrong.

To avoid this mistake in future, declare your variables with an explicit datatype. The following would never have compiled:

```
List<SearchViewModel> searchResults = Mapper.Map<List<Shop>, SearchViewModel>(shopList);
```

Try this instead:

```
List<SearchViewModel> searchResults = Mapper.Map<List<Shop>, List<SearchViewModel>>(shopList);
```

Comment: This was it - I've been scratching my head for hours over this. Lesson learned!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have the `AutoMapper` set up in one of my projects (tailored to your example). I am using a static class and a static `IMapper` property inside the same class.

```
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static IMapper EntityMapper { get; set; }

        static EntityMap()
        {
            EntityMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Shop, SearchViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Title, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.TITLE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Subtitle, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.SUB_TITLE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.ProductType, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.PRODUCT_TYPE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Language, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.PRODUCT_LANGUAGE))
                    .ForMember(x => x.Description, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.BRIEF_DESC));
            });
        }
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```
    EntityMap.EntityMapper.Map<List<Shop>, SearchViewModel>(shopList);
```