# AutoMapper one-to-many and View Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, entity-framework, automapper

I get the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type.
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> ========================================================================
>
> List1 -> PSS_MembersViewModel (Destination member list)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PRS.Domain.Entities.PSS_Members,
> PRS.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
> PRS_MD.ViewModels.PSS_MembersViewModel (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: ID Full_Name Mobile Mobile2 Email PSS_Team_ID
> PSS_Teams PSS_Trip_Members Active

My entities:

```
public class PSS_Members : Entity
{
    public PSS_Members()
    {
        PSS_Trip_Members = new HashSet<PSS_Trip_Members>();
    }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Mobile2 { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? PSS_Team_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual PSS_Teams PSS_Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_Trip_Members> PSS_Trip_Members { get; set; }     
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class PSS_Teams : Entity
{  
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_Members> PSS_Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_Team_Support> PSS_Team_Support { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_Vehicles> PSS_Vehicles { get; set; }      
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

View Models:

```
public class PSS_MembersViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Mobile2 { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? PSS_Team_ID { get; set; }
//  public virtual PSS_Teams PSS_Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual PSS_TeamsViewModel PSS_Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_Trip_Members> PSS_Trip_Members { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }     
}

public class PSS_TeamsViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSS_MembersViewModel> PSS_Members { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper:

```
cfg.CreateMap<PSS_Members, PSS_MembersViewModel>()
   .ReverseMap();

cfg.CreateMap<PSS_Teams, PSS_TeamsViewModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
   .ReverseMap();
```

Controller:

```
var members = _pSS_MembersService.GetAll().ToList();
var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PSS_MembersViewModel>(members);
var teams = _pSS_TeamsService.GetAll().ToList();
var mappedteams = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PSS_TeamsViewModel>(teams);
model.PSS_Teams = mappedteams;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Mapper Unmapped members were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359999/auto-mapper-unmapped-members-were-found)

Comment: @BenSteinberg See my answer.

Comment: @aaron - yes thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map a list of Entities to a single View Model.

```
// var mappedteams = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PSS_TeamsViewModel>(teams);
   var mappedteams = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<PSS_TeamsViewModel>>(teams);
```