# How to tell AutoMapper to ignore (not map) base class properties?

Tags: c#, automapper

We're using ViewModels based on a special class that has a few properties. These properties don't have mapping properties in the models. How can I tell AutoMapper to ignore these properties globally? This is what I tried but I still get errors related to these properties. Also, is there a way to pass multiple properties to be ignored in the CreateMap?

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
          cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
          cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi => !pi.Name.InList("HiddenSwitch","ErrorMessage",
                                   "SuccessMessage", "WarningMessage","DuplicateForm");
    });

   public static IMapper Mapper;

   public static void Configure()
   {
       Mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
       mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
   }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the answers here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest, not a duplicate, but definitely similar

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I also found that I can use
public static MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("HiddenSwitch");
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("ErrorMessage");
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("SuccessMessage");
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("WarningMessage");
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("DuplicateForm");
            cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            
        });