# Automapper how to ignore missing properties in destination child properties

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper-6

I've followed this answer ([http://stackoverflow.com/a/31182390/58508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest/31182390#31182390)) to ignore missing properties in destination and it works fine, but I don't know how to do the same for children collection properties.

For example, I've a CustomerViewModel and Customer classes. CustomerViewModel has less properties than Customer class, the mapping from CustomerViewModel to Customer works fine.
CustomerViewModel has a property `public virtual ICollection<ContactViewModel> Contacts { get; set; }` with less properties than Customer property `public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }` property. When I apply a mapping additional destination properties are overwritten in Contact.

My mapping profile is:

```
CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, Customer>(MemberList.Source);
CreateMap<ContactViewModel, Contact>(MemberList.Source);
```

Regards